# Can I use DOM query methods against a Fetch API response?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm trying to automate interaction with an old web interface that currently only exposes user-driven forms, so I need to scrape some information from a web page with a dynamic request.

If I use an XHR, I can treat the response as a `Document`, which lets me use methods like `querySelector` to retrieve information from specific nodes.  I'd like to try to use the Fetch API, though, which only gives me a [Body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body).  This has `blob`, `formData`, `json`, and `text`, but I don't see anything that would let me treat it as a `Document`.

Am I missing something?  Can I get a Document or something else query-able directly from `fetch`?  If not, is there a simple way to take a string (from `Body.text()`) and turn it into a Document?

Comment: Could you add the text into a dummy elements it's innerHTML and then query it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/DOMParser should help you create a document from a html string.

Comment: @Icepickle since I'm retrieving an entire HTML document (`<html>` tag on down), the only valid node I could insert it into would be under an `iframe`, I think, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: @Coderer You can use `querySelector` or whatever to get some portion of the document, and then take the node you get back from that and insert it wherever you want. (As in the example snippet in the answer, which just gets the first `section` element from the requested document.)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> Can I get a Document or something else query-able directly from fetch? If not, is there a simple way to take a string (from Body.text()) and turn it into a Document?

You can’t get a [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) back directly from the Fetch API itself. But you can use [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) and give its [`parseFromString()`](https://w3c.github.io/DOM-Parsing/#dom-domparser-parsefromstring) method the text the Fetch [`Body.text()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text) promise resolves to.

```js
fetch("https://enable-cors.org/")
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(text => {
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const htmlDocument = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/html");
    const section = htmlDocument.documentElement.querySelector("section");
    document.querySelector("div").appendChild(section);
  })
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.  I was hoping for something like `response.html()` but this works and only adds a few lines.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
async function fetchDocument(url) {        
    let response = await fetch(url);
    let text = await response.text();
    if (!fetchDocument.parser) fetchDocument.parser = new DOMParser(); // the dom parser is reusable
    return fetchDocument.parser.parseFromString(text, "text/html");
}

let doc = await fetchDocument(urlToFetch)
```

Comment: This is the same as the accepted answer.  It's actually worth noting, there's a nontrivial cost to allocating a new DOMParser, and they can be reused, so it's better to make one parser outside the function and use it for each call.

Comment: @Coderer Yes, it was based on that code, but written more concisely using async/await, and encapsulated into a function so that it can be easily reused. I also now added in your suggestion for the function to reuse one DOMParser instead of creating new ones, thanks